# Why won't my nested ScrollView scroll till the end?

Tags: android, listview, nestedscrollview

My ListView does not scroll to the end of the screen.
It stops right at the top of the last item.

Below are the two codes I have been playing around with to get it to scroll to the end.
The tab layout is supposed to scroll too, to make space for the ListView to scroll till the end.
This feature works on all the other Fragments but won't work with the ScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing.Serv_OverviewFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/serv_OverviewTab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/displayListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing.Serv_OverviewFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/displayListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I need some help.

Comment: Nesting scrollable Views is supposed to cause scroll issues. And it is considered a poor UI design.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes I agree with you. Is there a way I can resolve this? I do not want to use RecyclerView and I am tempted to remove the NestedScrollView and make it LinearLayout but I feel like that does not make sense. By the way, I appreciate the editing, I did not proofread.

Comment: `I am tempted to remove the NestedScrollView and make it LinearLayout` that's a good idea. `but I feel like that does not make sense.` Why?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein because although the ListView will scroll in the Fragment, the Tab Layout will not scroll up to make way for the fragment to scroll to the last item.

Comment: You don't need it to.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I don't need it to??? Why not? Anyway, I tried it though and there was no change.

Comment: What's the meaning of making the TabLayout scroll? It can stay in its place all the time, while the ListView scrolls to the end. That's what I call "header". Yes you may add headers and footers inside a ListView and make them scroll - but I hate those ones. I want mine to be always visible.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes, if the TabLayout stays in its place, the ListView does not scroll until the last item in the View.

Comment: I can't get it. It's quite a bit I'm using ListViews... never had such funny behaviours.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein mine is acting pretty funny but I am convinced there may be other factors affecting it.

Comment: Are you using a standard Android ListView? or some funny 3rd party thingies?